# How C# Method change the value of the parameter

Tags: c#, methods, parameter-passing

I am confused about how the code below works.
Why is the output not 10 but 5?

```
public class Program
{
    public  void MyFunc(int x){
        x = 10;
    }
    public void Main()
    {
        int x = 5;
        MyFunc(x);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `MyFunc(x)` does not pass `x` to `MyFunc`, it only passes the _value_ of `x`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c

Comment: Because x is passed by value, not by reference, so x in Main is never changed

Comment: Thank you all guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about the "ref keyword"
Now result is 10

```
 public static void MyFunc(ref int x)
        {
            x = 10;
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            int x = 5;
            MyFunc(ref x);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
```